# ionic 5 - keyboard hide input and page content in landscape mode

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5

Android keyboard hide input and page content rather than scroll up

I have also try
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard
npm install @ionic-native/keyboard

But non of them works

Also try to add the property in androidmanifest.xml but nothing change

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

My whole app works in Landscape mode
So same problem is persist on every input

Screenshot 1
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZiFm.jpg

Screenshot 2
https://i.stack.imgur.com/31gP7.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for you response but i have fixed this
here is the solution

There is an Android bug that prevents the keyboard from resizing the WebView when the app is in full screen (i.e. if StatusBar plugin is used to hide the StatusBar). This setting, if set to true, add a workaround that resizes the WebView even when the app is in full screen.

Boolean (false by default)

Possible values
false: doesn't resize the WebView when the app is in full screen.
true: resizes the WebView when the app is in full screen.
`<preference name="resizeOnFullScreen" value="true" />`

Comment: resizing do have some issues like my tab menu , went below the view port , any work around for that .. Thanks a lot for this fix
@Sunil

Answer (score 0):

for landscape, try this in your xml

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
```

for no keyboard on an input field, try this

[ionic-no-keyboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-no-keyboard)